# Right outer join with static values in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, outer-join

I have a table `table` and I'm trying to show all the rows with the `id` in a certain list. If there are no rows with this id, then I would display `null` values.

Obviously, if these `id`s I want to select were in a different table, then the solution was just a `right join` statement.

The problem is that such table does not exists and the user provides the list of `id`s as input.

I'm trying to solve this using the `right join (values ..) on ..=..` statement. But I'm unable to give a column name to the nested statement (with static `value`s). And so I'm unable to write a valid `on` clause.

For instance, I have the table `table`:

```
id val    
-- --
0 0.1
2 -0.5
7 1.1
```

Then the user dinamically select a list of `id`s, which is not necessary contained in the list of `id`s of the table. For instance, if the user select `0,1,2,3`, then I should diplay:

```
id val    
-- --
0  0.1
1  null
2  -0.5
3  null
```

I'm trying to do something like

```
select * from table right outer join (
    values (0),(1),(2),(3)
) as static_values on table.id = static_values[1]
```

Obviosuly `static_values[1]` is wrong, but I have to name the column to perform a `join` and I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: Which RDBMS please? e.g. In Sql Server you could pass a table parameter, and Oracle has options like array or nested tables as well.

Comment: Thanks for asking, DB2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
select * 
  from table 
 right outer join (values (0),(1),(2),(3)) as static_values(id) 
    on table.id = static_values.id
```

Comment: It works! thanks, I didn't knew the syntax `as table_alias(column aliases)`